# How to override login.phtml file? Is overriding working for template files?

Tags: magento2

I tried,

app/design/frontend/Magestore/sample/composer.json

```
{
"name": "magento/sample-module-theme",
"description": "N/A",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "~100.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0"
},
"type": "magento2-theme",
"version": "1.0.0",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ]
}
}
```

app/design/frontend/Magestore/sample/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/Magestore/sample',
__DIR__
);
```

app/design/frontend/Magestore/sample/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Magestore Sample Theme12</title>
<parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

app/design/frontend/Magestore/sample/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
        <action method="setTemplate">
         <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magestore_Sample::form/login.phtml</argument>
       </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/design/frontend/Magestore/sample/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml

```
<?php 
     echo $welcomeMessage = "Login Page";
 ?>
```

Comment: You need to set your theme from admin then your code will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check theme is applied or not. You can check your current theme by **ctr + U**, you can see current theme path in **.css** and **.js** file.

In your case **Magestore/Sample** display in **.css** and **.js** file path. If display it, theme is set properly.

Run below command

> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean
> ```

Now you can see your changes.

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: there is no effect

Comment: Check it with clean magento cache.

Comment: clear and disable cache

Comment: still no effect. In admin, Applied theme field is there in that one of the dropdown option is my theme but I have not applied and saved.

Comment: Apply my update answer code. It will work for you.

Comment: can you share your whole theme code like registration.php and theme.xml ? So that i can help you in proper way.

Comment: Just add this code in your layout xml, it is working code. I have tested.

Comment: i tried but no luck

Comment: @JagritiJoshi - See my updated code

Comment: Have you set theme as 'Sample' from admin?

Comment: when I set theme Sample then css and js is not applied and also customer login page does not get override

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60757/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-jassi).

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply override login.phtml file in your theme 
app/design/frontend/Magestore/Sample/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml
no need to write in layout file

```
 echo $welcomeMessage = "Login Page";
```

Comment: but still there is no effect

Comment: your theme is working  or not?

Comment: how to find theme is working or not?

Comment: open admin panel and see under Content->Design->Configuration->and check theme

Comment: please make sure your theme name is correct , make it Magestore/sample not Magestore/Sample.

Comment: my theme exist in admin and I also corrected Magestore/sample but still there is no effect